# Suddenly several VBA macro errors, mostly 32809

Tags: vba, excel

Suddenly my excel file is generating a lot of errors at startup.
No changes have been made to the file since before the errors started.

Example of errors:

**Error 438:**

```
Sheets("setup2").CheckBox4.Caption = "Lägg automatiskt till " & _ 
    Sheets("setup2").Range("L8").Value & " måndag efter jour."
```

**Error 32809:**

```
Worksheets(1).Visible = True
Worksheets(1).Cells(42, 3) = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Sheets("setup").Cells(43, 3) = Environ("UserName")
Worksheets(1).Cells(35, 13) = MostRecentDate
```

The workbook is not password protected.
It's Office 2013 (15.0.4659.1000) MSO (15.0.4659.1001)

Comment: Might be ralated to http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/11/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue. Created an application to track welding procedures. My machine was running Windows 7 and Excel 2010. Anything I created, then distributed to other machines with different OS's or different Excel versions would have 32809 errors, usually associated with selecting a worksheet

```
Sheets("Data Entry").Select
```

This would trigger an Application or run time error 32809.
I tried all of the fixes previously mentioned (delete all temp files, .exd files etc. No joy.

My solution ( may not work for you)

Opened the application on a machine that was Excel 2007.
Added one comment line of code of no consequence into one of the macros

```
Sheets(sheetName).Select 
'comment of no consequence
```

and saved it. This caused a recompile.
Closed and re-opened with Excel 2007 - all fixed.

If I add any code to these applications on my machine and then distribute, there is invariably an error when run, unless I get the application to recompile on the differing system. I sent the fixed version onto another machine running Excel 2007 and it worked fine.

Hope this makes sense and helps

Grant

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar post on error 32809:

[Excel VBA Run-time Error '32809' - Trying to Understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861288/excel-vba-run-time-error-32809-trying-to-understand-it)

They mention that the file may be corrupted and theirs a solution in the comments by Siddharth Rout:

> That is because the worksheet is corrupted. Try this. Create a new
>   sheet and copy every thing from that to the new sheet and then finally
>   delete that sheet. It will work. just tested and tried it.

Not sure if that will help you, but worth a try I guess.

Comment: It is even better to mark it as a duplicate (if it is so), and post a comment linking to the solution, instead of copying the answer.

Comment: i tried deleting that corrupted "Sheet", but I couldn't. While i'm pressing the delete button, the workbook goes to not-responding state. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Some ms updates could have brought on the 32809 error.
Replace all sheet-embedded buttons (and other controls) with new ones; you can do it manually or with some codes.

Comment: I couldn't delete it. If I try to delete the embedded buttons and controls, my Excel Workbook is going not-responding state. How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This same error started cropping up for me, and if it's happening to you when you share a VBA workbook with others this is probably your issue.

The root is a security update that Microsoft pushed in December 2014. The Microsoft Support page for this issue is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US

Here's the fix:

1. On the computer used to create the VBA Excel file, find an uninstall the relevant security patch under Windows Updates (`KB 2726958` for Office **2013**, `KB 2553154` for Office **2010**, or `KB 2596927` for Office **2007**).
2. After uninstalling the patch, open the VBA file you're having issues with. Make some minor edit to the VBA code so Excel recompiles (just in case).
3. Save the file and test on other computers having the Active-X issues.

Hopefully this helps someone that was in my position this morning. This is a frustrating issue, and it's hard to track down a resolution.

---

Sources & notes:

[1] Details for the Security Update from Microsoft Update:

> **Name**: `Security Update for Microsoft Office 2010 (KB2553154) 32-Bit Edition`
>
> **Download size**: `542 KB`
>
> **Details**: `A security vulnerability exists in Microsoft Office 2010 32-Bit Edition that could allow arbitrary code to run when a maliciously modified file is opened. This update resolves that vulnerability.`
>
> **More information**: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2553154

[2] *"Cannot insert object" error in an ActiveX custom Office solution after you install the MS14-082 security update* at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3025036/EN-US

[3] *Relief for botched Excel patches KB 2553154, 2726958 missing from January Patch Tuesday* at http://www.infoworld.com/article/2868062/operating-systems/january-patch-tuesday-a-yawn-and-several-whimpers-no-relief-for-last-months-kb-2553154-2726958-botc.html

[4] *Form Controls stop working after December 2014 Updates* at http://blogs.technet.com/b/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/archive/2014/12/18/forms-controls-stop-working-after-december-2014-updates-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

before:
 (worked fine in golden years)

n = sheets(1).name

now:

dim ws as new worksheet

set ws = activeworkbook.sheets(1)

n = ws.name

Comment: Before what? Could you elaborate slightly?

Answer (score 0):

We found success using the following approach.

1. Open a blank version of excel.
2. Disable ActiveX controls in Excel Options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjtsm.jpg)

3. Open the offending file. (Click through any error received upon open)
4. Save the file as a new name.
5. Activate ActiveX controls.

We found distributing this file after the steps above resolved the error for all users.

Hope this helps someone else.