# Excel Macro opens with run time error 32809

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Macro Enabled workbook that I created on Excel 2013.  The workbook's macros work well with my computer but does not work on some other computers even if they are using Excel 2013. Works on 7/10 computers I tried both on windows 7 and 8. When I send it to someone's computer that does not work this is what happens:

They open the workbook and once the user clicks "enable content" the workbook errors out "run time error '32809': Application-defined or object-defined error"

debug shows it getting stuck on 2nd line of code below:

```
private sub workbook open()
Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "impacts"
**Worksheets(2).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "yesnoo"** This line errors
```

if I comment out these two lines, the workbook will open but the combobox21 on worksheet(2) gets renamed to combobox22 and does not work but the first combobox on worksheet(1) loads and functions fine.

I would like to add that if I comment out the lines

```
Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "impacts"
Worksheets(2).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "yesnoo"
```

I get the error now that "Can't exit design mode because control ' dattimepicker21' cannot be created

Comment: Have you tried renaming the problem combobox on the 2nd worksheet?

Comment: the most recent Excel version(s) have only 1 sheet upon opening (not 3 like the earlier versions) so you will get an error referencing the non-existent sheet

Comment: @bsapaka assuming the workbook *already has two sheets*... anyways that would raise a Subscript Out of Range error, not a 32809 error :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27591879/suddenly-several-vba-macro-errors-mostly-32809

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861288/excel-vba-run-time-error-32809-trying-to-understand-it

Comment: Sheet(s) or workbook may have become corrupted. That seems to be the consensus around this error number.

Comment: I would like to add that if I comment out the lines Worksheets(1).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "impacts"
Worksheets(2).OLEObjects("ComboBox21").ListFillRange = "yesnoo" I get the error now that "Can't exit design mode because control ' dattimepicker21' cannot be created

Comment: I have 7 sheets in the workbook. What would the steps be if the workbook got corrupted? And if corrupted why would it work perfectly fine on most computers? @DavidZemens

Comment: Unfortunately, Excel is often really that unpredictable. Trying to recreate the workbook from scratch (as tough as it may be) is crucial to find out if there's a real problem or if the file just got corrupted along the way somehow.

Comment: What happens if you do `Worksheets(2).OLEObjects("ComboBox22").ListFillRange = "yesnoo"`?  You're going to have to open the file, skip/ignore the errors, make the change to the code, save & close & reopen.

Comment: See this also, which seems very much similar to your problem: http://superuser.com/questions/874349/excel-runtime-error-32809-corrupt-workbooks

Answer (score 0):

I found and fixed the problem, the machines that were not working were missing MSCOMCT2.OCX

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/date-picker-dropdown-in-excel-2013/71decdcd-6cc6-4a70-b1ab-20294a2a315a