# Object defined error when looping into ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have a simple code :

```
Dim Sheet As Variant

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.print Sheet.Name
Next Sheet
```

But when I run it I got the error on the second sheet

> Run-time error '32809'
>
> Application-defined or object-defined error

Where does it come from ?

EDIT:
Here the lib used in the project
[image: Here the lib used in the project]

Comment: This `Sheet.Name = Sheet.Name` doesn't make any sense at all. I also don't see why you increase `i` but you don't use it anywhere.

Comment: I use it in a very large loop, it's for debugging purpose only.

Comment: Ok, but this minimal example is worthless because it does not fail. This code is working fine even if it doesn't make any sense. Any possibility that the workbook or any worksheet is protected?

Comment: When I run this code I got the error  "Run-time error '32809'" that's my problem

Comment: Might be, but not if you open a new workbook and paste that code into a sub. Then it runs without any issues here.

Comment: I got an update, it work on Excel 2016 but not in Excel 2007. the weird thing is I can't access the name of the sheet though code but with the "Watches" I can go find this information. No problem if I copy this module into a new workbook.

Comment: Please make sure your worksheets or the workbook are not protected. See if `Debug.Print Sheet.Name` instead of `Sheet.Name = Sheet.Name` works. If that works it is no problem to read the sheet name but to write it. Then there must be any protection.

Comment: Yep, I used Debug.print and I got the same error with the following code:

Dim Sheet As Variant

For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Debug.Print Sheet.Name
Next Sheet

Comment: Isn't `Sheet` the name of an existing object? On the very least it is bad practice to reuse existing object names as variables, but it might even cause unexpected behaviour. Try renaming your variable.

Comment: I was thinking a locked sheet & workbook, but that would raise error 1004 rather than 32809.  This links has plenty of possible solutions:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861288/excel-vba-run-time-error-32809-trying-to-understand-it

Comment: As suggested I try renaming the variable but it has no effect.

Comment: Do you by any chance have activex controls on the sheet(s) that the code fails with?

Comment: I tried copy it but delete the old sheet result in Excel crashing

Comment: @vacip I tried with different random letter, i tried with "boopssd" for example.

Comment: ActiveWorkBook is my suspicion for being the culprit here. Do you have any code that refers to multiple workbooks? And do you forget to set the focus to each new workbook you mess with?