# vba to move data to new tab, sort and subtotal excel

Tags: excel, sorting, copy, subtotal, vba

thank you for the help- novice, but learning
I have a worksheet need to do the following:
1. check each date
2. move rows where data values are the same to a new sheet
3. rename that tab the mm.dd of the value

then for each sheet created
1. sort by column D Ascending
2. group by column 4 (person email) subtotal column 7 (quantity)

at then end display a "Complete!" message box

code is below, but I cannot get it to complete through the first name of "person email"   Help is appreciated!
Link to see Desired Result - [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAuEi.png)
Link to see starting point- [starting point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M32vM.png)

```
Sub TransferReport()
Dim WS      As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'Check each date
 For Each DateEnd In Sheet1.Columns(3).Cells
    If DateEnd.Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'Stop program if no date
    If IsDate(DateEnd.Value) Then
        shtName = Format(DateEnd.Value, "mm.dd")    'Change date to valid tab name

        On Error GoTo errorhandler  'if no Date Sheet, go to errorhandler to create new tab
        If Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2").Value = "" Then
           DateEnd.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A2")
           Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1:M1").Columns.AutoFit
        Else
            DateEnd.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
Next

Exit Sub
errorhandler:
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'Create new tab
ActiveSheet.Name = shtName  'Name tab with date
Sheet1.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Rows(1) 'Copy heading to new tab
Resume

'SortAllSheets()
   'Ascending sort on A:M using column D, all sheets in workbook
   For Each WS In Worksheets
      WS.Columns("A:M").Sort Key1:=WS.Columns("D"), Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlAscending
   Next WS

 'SubTotals()
    For Each WS In Worksheets
                    With wsDst
                 LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A1:M" & LastRow).Subtotal GroupBy:=4, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(7), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
            End With
        Next
```

Images are added showing before picture and desired results:
BEFORE PICTURE - [before data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TAuEi.png)

after picture-  [desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M32vM.png)

Comment: Each time you run your code, if data in Sheet1 column C is a date, either a sheet is created and data copied or, if sheet already exist, copy the row from Sheet1. If you run the code several times, duplicate data will be copied. Ordering and subtotals are not working, at least in part because the for each loops are wrong. But is not at all clear what you want to achieve. If you can add some details to understand your aim it would be helpful. Also take into account that, in your code, data with same day/month but different year will end up in the same sheet, and reference to year will be lost.

Comment: @cmarg I have attached links to the source doc and the desired result. to the original post.   I think it may help - thank you for looking -

Comment: Please upload screenshots of starting point and desired results. There is a link to this task. I never open online files...

Comment: @cMarg I've added the screenshots and removed the files - stack overflow would not allow screenprints -hover over the link and you can see they are .png files - thank you!

Comment: So the code to transfer rows to the new sheets, creating them if necessary, works? (If you expect to run it multiple times and avoid duplicates, it could start by deleting all sheets but sheet1, if any). Do you want to to do your sorts and subtotals to Sheet1 as well to those organized by date? It looks like it would be trying to do that as currently coded.

Comment: Not sure but wondering if WS.Columns("D") should be WS.Columns("D:D") or even WS.Columns(4)

Comment: @JeremyKahan the code to copy single sheet to multiple sheets does work and the tabs are names.   It will not sort, or subtotal the way that it needs to.   I can get the code to do it separately (so 3 macros but not together).   There are hundreds of the "before" picture generated weekly, the desired result parses the data out so that it can be easily transferred to compare forecasted results to actuals.

Comment: oh wait, your exit sub means your later code is never reached! Move it and the errorhandler below the other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. I don't like to add a sheet onerror, since it will add a sheet whenever there is an error. So the following code scan for all sheets, and add them to an array. In the loop, after finding a date, checks if sheet name already exist. Keep in mind that code will add data each time you run the code (so there will be duplicated data). Also data from different years but same day/month will be gather together, with no reference to year.

If you want to keep your code, pay attention to:

1)`Exit Sub` does not allow execution of the rest of your code.

2)`For Each WS In Worksheets` has wrong sintax

3) `Worksheets(shtName).Range("A1:M1").Columns.AutoFit` only take into account first row for Autofit

4) `If DateEnd.Value = "" Then Exit Sub` will exit code if there is a cell in between with no date

```
Sub TransferReport()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MainSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DateEnd As Range
Dim NextLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ArraySheets() As String
Dim shtName As String


'Store sheet names in array
ReDim ArraySheets(1 To Sheets.Count)
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        ArraySheets(i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Name
Next

'Check each date
Set MainSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = MainSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsDate(MainSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
        shtName = Format(MainSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value, "mm.dd")
        If Not IsInArray(shtName, ArraySheets) Then
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set WS = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)) 'Create new tab
                WS.Name = shtName 'Name tab with date
                MainSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=WS.Rows(1) 'Copy heading to new tab
                ArraySheets(UBound(ArraySheets)) = shtName
                ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(1 To UBound(ArraySheets) + 1) As String 'add new sheet name to array
            End With
        End If

        NextLastRow = Worksheets(shtName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MainSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Cells(NextLastRow, 1)
        Worksheets(shtName).Columns("A:M").Columns.AutoFit
    End If
Next

'   'Ascending sort on A:M using column D, all sheets in workbook
   For Each WS In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      WS.Columns("A:M").Sort Key1:=WS.Columns("D"), Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlAscending
      LastRow = WS.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      WS.Range("A1:M" & LastRow).Subtotal GroupBy:=4, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(7), Replace:=True, PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
   Next WS

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

**EDIT**

Seems that you want to make a report. I usually feel uncomfortable with grouping, and like to explicitly state what I want. Of course this is a personal preference. But if it is also your case, try the code below. Each time you run the macro, report sheets will be deleted and new ones created. Also there is no modification in main sheet (`"Sheet1"`). This way you have more control on the output.

```
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MainSheet As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim DateEnd As Range
Dim NextLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim ArraySheets() As String
Dim shtName As String
Dim TheRow As Long
Dim TheSum As Variant
Dim WSName As Variant, TheCustomerMail As String


'Store Main sheet name in array
ReDim ArraySheets(1 To 1)
ArraySheets(1) = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Name

'Delete all previous sheets, except main one ("Sheet1")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Sheets(i).Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Check each date
Set MainSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
LastRow = MainSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If IsDate(MainSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
        shtName = Format(MainSheet.Cells(i, 3).Value, "mm.dd")
        If Not IsInArray(shtName, ArraySheets) Then
            With ThisWorkbook
                Set WS = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)) 'Create new tab
                WS.Name = shtName 'Name tab with date
                MainSheet.Rows(1).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=WS.Rows(1) 'Copy heading to new tab
                ReDim Preserve ArraySheets(1 To UBound(ArraySheets) + 1) As String
                ArraySheets(UBound(ArraySheets)) = shtName
            End With
        End If

        NextLastRow = Worksheets(shtName).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        MainSheet.Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(shtName).Cells(NextLastRow, 1)
        Worksheets(shtName).Columns("A:M").Columns.AutoFit
    End If
Next

'Ascending sort on A:M using column D, all sheets in workbook
For Each WSName In ArraySheets
    TheCustomerMail = "" 'Starting name
    TheSum = ""

    If WSName <> "Sheet1" Then 'Only sort "new" sheets, not main one
        Worksheets(WSName).Columns("A:M").Sort Key1:=Worksheets(WSName).Columns("D"), Header:=xlYes, Order1:=xlAscending
        LastRow = Worksheets(WSName).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        TheRow = LastRow + 1
        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If i = 1 Then
                Worksheets(WSName).Cells(TheRow, 5) = TheSum
            Else
                If Worksheets(WSName).Cells(i, 4).Value <> TheCustomerMail Then
                    Worksheets(WSName).Cells(TheRow, 5) = TheSum
                    Worksheets(WSName).Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    Worksheets(WSName).Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
                    TheRow = i + 1
                    TheSum = Worksheets(WSName).Cells(i, 5).Value
                    TheCustomerMail = Worksheets(WSName).Cells(i, 4).Value
                    'Worksheets(WSName).Rows(i + 1).Columns("A:M").Interior.ColorIndex = 16
                    'Worksheets(WSName).Rows(i + 1).Columns("A:M").Font.ColorIndex = 2
                    Worksheets(WSName).Rows(i + 1).Columns("A:M").Font.Bold = True
                    Worksheets(WSName).Cells(i + 1, 4) = "Total of " & TheCustomerMail & ":"
                    Worksheets(WSName).Columns("D").Columns.AutoFit
                Else
                    TheSum = TheSum + Worksheets(WSName).Cells(i, 5).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

Comment: ran code, but getting a subscript out of range error.

Comment: Which line? You can start macro and go step by step with F8.

Comment: You're right. I'm not an expert. Yesterday the code was working, but today I had problems. However I copied the data and the macro to a new excel file and now it works (following a comment by Siddharth Rout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19861288/1726522)). Also I noticed that if you want to run the code again, you must get rid of grouping before ordering.

Comment: replaced "thisworkbook" with activeworkbook and it works like a charm!  I should have specified that in my question THANK YOU!!! -