# Error Code 32809 in Excel (different from any other similar question)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working from home using the Citrix Workspace platform for my work and recently I've been programming a project on excel and after a lot of tests everything seemed to be working properly. However, there are quite a few people at my job that are using a laptop of the company which is connected to a VPN to access their files and work from the laptop. When they try to open the excel and the first macro starts, they get the 32809 error code. I have tried everything such as saving the file as .xlsx and then back to .xlsm but it's not working for them.. everything is working perfectly for me though...

Here's the simple code where they get an error:
[image: Code where the error is:]

And here's the error message:

[image: error message]

Comment: As a general principle you want to obtain a reference to a Worksheet object using the `CodeName` rather than accessing a member of the Worksheets collection based on the `Name` as this makes your code more durable in case you decide to change what displays on the tab. If you want to change "Step 1" to "Log-in" for example then you would have to update the code to reflect this `.Worksheets("Log-in")`, whereas if you used `Sheet1` or whatever then you don't have to worry about it at all. `CodeName` and `Name` are listed next to each other in the object browser list so should be easy to find.

Comment: Regarding the actual error my guess would be that the use of the VPN is breaking the `Workbooks("...")` call as you use a filename without any path specified. Can't say that is for sure but is something worth exploring. Try reading that into a separately declared workbook variable the line before and see if you get an issue there instead.

Comment: The Workbook "Avis Excel 2.0.xlsm" would have to be open on the user's machine before your code can run. If this is the workbook that contains the code try qualifying the worksheet with `ThisWorkbook` instead of the name. However, bear in mind that Excel may not fully load the workbook before the user grants permission (as you see when opening a workbook received by email).

Comment: Have you tried every suggestion mentioned [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19861288/excel-vba-run-time-error-32809-trying-to-understand-it)

Answer (score 0):

Alright so after few tests I found out that the problem was the DataPicker from microsoft that was causing bunch of problems... Once I removed the tool, the problem disappeared. Based on the research that I did, some computers don't recognize this tool which ends up in an error.